# No unbiased estimator of $\min\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, point-estimation

The problem is stated as:

> Suppose $X, Y$ are independent and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, 1), Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, 1)$ with unknown parameters $\mu_1, \mu_2$. Prove that unbiased estimation of $\theta=\min \left\{\mu_1, \mu_2\right\}$ does not exist.

Here's my sketch:

Let $p(\mu, x)$ denote the pdf of $\mathcal N(\mu,1)$. Suppose $T(X, Y)$ is an unbiased estimator. Then $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}T(x,y)p(\mu_1,x)p(\mu_2,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\min\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}.$$
Let $$q(\mu_2,x)=\int_{\mathbb R} T(x,y)p(\mu_2,y)\mathrm dy.$$
We have $$\int_{\mathbb R} p(\mu_1, x)q(\mu_2,x)\mathrm dx=\min\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}. (*)$$

Intuitively, since $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are separated on the left, it cannot be something related to the order of $\mu_1,\mu_2$. If this is true, then we are done.

But I am stuck here and need some hints.

There is proof of the original problem mentioned by
User1865345. But it uses the fact that $\min$ is not differentiable somewhere, which is not an essential property. We can slightly adjust the function to some pseudo-minimums like something pointed out by Henry. I think the unbiased estimator should still not exist, due to the intuition above.

A specific question is: whether there exists $p,q$ that satisfies $(*)$ if we forget everything and just set $p,q$ to be integrable.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, it solves the original problem. But I'm interested in some proof that does not depend on the smoothness of the target function. In my intuition, if we slightly change $\min\{\mu_1, \mu_2\}$ to make it smooth at $\mu_1=\mu_2$, the unbiased estimator should still not exist.

Comment: If you want a smooth pseudo-minimum, try something like $\frac1k \log_e\left(e^{kx}+e^{ky}\right)$ for some negative $k$  (positive $k$ would give you a smooth pseudo-maximum).  This will give you a value in $\left[\min(x,y)-\frac{\log_e(2)}{-k}, \min(x,y)\right]$ so by increasing the magnitude of $k$ you can get as close as you want

Comment: Surely, I know there exists something like this. What I want to show  is that anything that depends on the size relationship of $\mu_1,\mu_2$ should not be estimable, including these smooth pseudo-minimums.

Comment: @SoonPrinceton, I would ask you to edit your post to ask the more general query that you have raised.

Comment: @User1865345 Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my post.

Comment: To make the question appear less of a duplicate, perhaps the title should be edited too...maybe "Prove there is no unbiased estimator of $\min\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$ without using differentiability" or "Extending proof there is no unbiased estimator of $\min\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$ to include smooth pseudo-minimums"?

Comment: @SoonPrinceton you might not be satisfied with the proof given in the other question, but it is still a (very clear) duplicate. If you want a different approach of proof then clarify this in your question.